# ERROR implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I don't know why

> "implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'"

line was an Error?

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "phpmysql.example.com.e_seefy"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

In this line, I just add

> "implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])"

for connecting my app to firebase. I also include the last line in this code.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: what is the output error on build tab ? could you just explain more ...

Comment: Thank you but I've already fix it. I just inserted "//noinspection GradleCompatible"